# Ассемблер: удаление файла

Tags: файлы, ассемблер, fasm

Всем привет. Начал писать на асме, но возник вопрос: как удалить файл (использую Flat Assembler).
Написал код, но не работает он:

```
format PE GUI 4.0
include '%include%/win32ax.inc'

.data

sFile DB 'C:\file.txt',0

.code
start:

    push offset sFile
    call DeleteFileA
    push 0
    call ExitProcess

.end start
```

Как же удалить файл?

Comment: что значит "не работает"? какое возвращаемое значение? где вызов GetLastError?

Comment: Пишет ошибку в строке :    push offset sFile
С fasm только 2 дня )

Answer (score 2):

Видоизмененный оригинал:

```
format PE GUI 4.0
include '%include%/win32ax.inc'

.data

sFile DB 'file.txt',0 ; из корня диска C: не удаляет, разве что запускать с админ. правами

.code
start:

    push sFile ; директивы offset в fasm нет. Имя метки без квадратных скобок как раз и означает взятие ее смещения (адреса)
    call [DeleteFile] ; окончание A не обязательно в данном случае
    push 0
    call [ExitProcess]

.end start
```

По поводу invoke:

```
invoke Func, a, b, c, d
```

это то же что

```
stdcall [Func], a, b, c, d
```

и то же что

```
push d
push c
push b
push a
call [Func]
```

Answer (score 0):

а почему бы не воспользоваться синтаксисом, который предлагает fasm? Где то так:

```
invoke  MessageBox,0,[_strbuf],_msgcap,MB_ICONINFORMATION+MB_OK
```

В Вашем случае код будет выглядеть где то так

```
format PE GUI 4.0
include '%include%/win32ax.inc'
.data

sFile DB 'C:\file.txt',0

.code
start:
    invoke DeleteFileA, sFile
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

.end start
```

Comment: а без него работает? Это случайно скопировалось с моего примера.

Comment: На эту    invoke DeleteFileA, [sFile]   строку ругается )

Comment: Убрал include '%include%/cmd.inc',но все равно на invoke DeleteFileA, [sFile] ругается

Comment: как ругается? пишет "не могу найти функцию" или "я уже звоню в эфбиай"?

Comment: ERROR: invalid size of operand.
Instruction: push[sFile]
Вот так.
Скрин : rghost.ru/45806293.view

Comment: Поставил flat assembler, собрал пример. что бы полностью заработало,  нужно поправить строку

    invoke DeleteFileA, [sFile]

на

    invoke DeleteFileA, sFile

Правда, удалить  файл в корне диска С мне не удавалось (подозреваю, что это происки 7 винды). Но в одном каталоге с программой удаляло на ура.